# Meaning of playing the flute when someone has died

Tags: death, judaism

In Mt 9:23 we read:

> And when Jesus came to the ruler’s house and saw the flute players and the crowd making a commotion, ...

Was or is playing the flute when someone has died a Jewish tradition or rather a tradition from a neighbouring people?
What is the meaning of it?

I have consulted the comments here but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: It was the local custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutes of various types are evident in both ancient Egyptian and Assyrian monuments so it is likely that the Israelites would have inherited flute-playing from these civilizations.

[image: Ancient Egyptian flute player]

Regarding its use in association with funerals, the prophet Jeremiah makes clear that even God spoke of the flute to signify His mourning:

> I will bring to an end in Moab, says the Lord, those who offer
> sacrifice at a high place and make offerings to their gods.  *Therefore
> my heart moans for Moab like a flute, and my heart moans like a flute
> for the people of Kir-heres*; for the riches they gained have perished.
> (Jer. 48:35-36)

The [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12180-pipe) adds:

> Among the later Jews flute-playing was considered so essential at
> funerals that even the poorest would not do without it.
> In the days of the Old Testament there were no flute-players in the Temple orchestra.

On the other hand, flutes or pipes were also used to create joy. Mt. 11:17 says:

> We have piped unto you, and ye have not danced; we have mourned unto
> you, and ye have not lamented.

This may refer to a different instrument than a traditional flute. The above-cited article mentions:

> A second kind of wind-instrument, known from very early times, was the
> "'ugab," which was essentially an instrument to express joyousness,
> and was played for the amusement of the people, but never at divine
> service. According to tradition, which connects the use of the 'ugab
> with Jubal (Gen. iv. 21), the instrument was a bagpipe ("sumpongah";
> Dan. iii. 5).

**So yes, it was a Jewish tradition to use flutes to express mourning. However, this is no longer the case today in Jewish funerary rites, where [music is generally discouraged](https://rfhr.com/jewish-funeral/).**

Answer (score 1):

The operative noun in Matt 9:23 is αὐλητής (aulétés) = flute player.  It occurs only in Matt 9:23 and Rev 18:22.

However, the cognate verb αὐλέω (auleó) = to play the flute, occurs in Matt 11:17, Luke 7:23, 1 Cor 14:7; the first two allude to people playing the flute at a funeral dirge.

[Another cognate noun, αὐλὸς (aulos) means "flute" and is found only in 1 Cor 14:7.]

Benson summarizes this well:

> The original word means flute-players. Musical instruments were used
> by the Jews, as well as the heathens, in their lamentations for the
> dead, to sooth the melancholy of surviving friends by soft and solemn
> notes. And there were persons who made it their business to perform
> this, while others sung to their music. Flutes were used especially on
> the death of children; louder instruments on the death of grown
> persons. Chardin says, that even now, in the East, the concourse of
> people where persons lie dead is incredible. Every body runs thither,
> the poor and the rich: and the former more especially make a strange
> noise.

**APPENDIX - Barnes comments on Matt 9:23**

> The expressions of grief at the death of a friend, in Eastern
> countries, are extreme. As soon as a person dies, all the females in
> the family set up a loud and doleful cry. They continue it as long as
> they can without taking breath, and the shriek of wailing dies away in
> a low sob. Nor do the relatives satisfy themselves with these
> expressions of violent grief. They hire persons of both sexes, whose
> employment it is to mourn for the dead in the like frantic manner. See
> Amos 5:16; Jeremiah 9:20. They sing the virtues of the deceased,
> recount his acts, dwell on his beauty, strength, or learning; on the
> comforts of his family and home, and in doleful strains ask him why he
> left his family and friends.
>
> To all this they add soft and melancholy music. They employ
> "minstrels" to aid their grief, and to increase the expressions of
> their sorrow. This violent grief continues, commonly, eight days. In
> the case of a king, or other very distinguished personage, it is
> prolonged through an entire month. This grief does not cease at the
> house; it is exhibited in the procession to the grave, and the air is
> split with the wailings of real and of hired mourners. Professor
> Hackett ("Illustrations of Scripture," pp. 121, 122) says: "During my
> stay at Jerusalem I frequently heard a singular cry issuing from the
> houses in the neighborhood of the place where I lodged, or from those
> on the streets through which I passed. It was to be heard at all hours
> in the morning, at noonday, at evening, or in the deep silence of night. For some time I was at a loss to understand the cause of this
> strange interruption of the stillness which, for the most part, hangs
> so oppressively over the lonely city. Had it not been so irregular in
> its occurrence, I might have supposed it to indicate some festive
> occasion; for the tones of voice (yet hardly tones so much as shrieks)
> used for the expression of different feelings sound so much alike to
> the unpracticed ear, that it is not easy always to distinguish the
> mournful and the joyous from each other.
>
> I ascertained, at length, that this special cry was, no doubt, in most
> instances, the signal of the death of some person in the house from
> which it was heard. It is customary, when a member of the family is
> about to die, for the friends to assemble around him and watch the
> ebbing away of life, so as to remark the precise moment when he
> breathes his last, upon which they set up instantly a united outcry,
> attended with weeping, and often with beating upon the breast, and
> tearing out the hair of the head. This lamentation they repeat at
> other times, especially at the funeral, both during the procession to
> the grave and after the arrival there, as they commit the remains to
> their last resting-place."